# CSS border/outline image over image

Tags: image, css, border, outline

I have an image that needs a border-image over the image and not around it.

The border is an transparent png.
See here what happens if I use border:

[image]

You can see that the image holds a white background.
I would like to have the border to be over the image. After some Googleling I found `outline`. Here I can set a negative value. The problem here is that `outline` can't hold images......

I tried setting negative values on margin for the image and the border but that didn't help.

Anyone ideas?

Here is the code (not very interesting):

```
<div class="top_img">
    <!-- some content -->
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
<style>
    background-image: url(the_image.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-size: cover;    
    border: 20px solid transparent;
    border-image: url(images/border_image.png) 30 round;
</style>
```

Comment: Why not just absolutely position the frame over the img if it is a transparent png?

Comment: Because it needs to scale. But thank you for that option. I didn't think of that. I fixed it using padding around the object so the border is pushed over the image. With some background positioning it works great now.